# Vue3 Component doesn't render in production when using v-bind:href require()

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Everything works fine when developing but once I export for production 1 component doesn't render and instead gets replaced by <!--->

After some debugging, I discovered that this happens because of require()

I have images with dynamic URLs that look like this:

```
:src="require(`@/assets/path/${variable}`)"
```

This works in dev but once I build the app for production the component doesn't render.

When I replace the path with

```
src="@/assets/path/file.png"
```

The component shows up and works properly

Is it something that I can provide to webpack in vue.config.js?

Is there a way to use variables in path without require()?

Comment: You're using Webpack and not Vite with Vue3?

Comment: Correct. I just assume something goes wrong when running npm run build but can't figure out why. Looked for alternatives to require() but nothing really works

Comment: did you tried `import()` maybe? Or why didnt you just use `:src="'@/assets/path/' + variable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression inside **v-bind** is executed at runtime, webpack aliases at compile time.

Move require() from html template to data() and it should work in production.

Simple example:

```
<template>
<img :src="getImg" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Example',
    data() {
        return {
            file: 'image',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getImg() {
            return require(`@/assets/images/${this.file}.png`)
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. I tried it before posting actually but was feeding require() the path as a variable as well. Turns out require() needs at least some of the path provided to be static in order to work properly.